# Microsoft Launcher on Xiaomi Redmi Note 11S reports false data to Microsoft

Tags: xiaomi, launcher, android-11, redmi-note-11

I am using [Microsoft Launcher](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.microsoft.launcher) to control time spend by my daughters with their mobile phones. On the mobile app side things seems to be working fine and dandy, as Microsoft Launcher correctly measures and counts that time:

[image]

The problem is that, after I have "upgraded" their old phones to 2 x Xiaomi Redmi Note 11S 6/64GB, it seems that this app is reporting an incorrect values to [Microsoft servers](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/family-safety) / [Microsoft Family Safety](https://account.microsoft.com/family/home) service:

[image]

Or sometimes it reports nothing:

[image]

Is there anything I can do about it (tried uninstall and install the app again, restarted device many times, to no avail.)? Is there any "live human" support at Microsoft that I could call to get a help? Or browsing forums and asking is my only option?

Answer (score 1):

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/contactus
Remember that they can bypass the restrictions on the launcher by entering apps directly or by switching the launcher.